# What is use case for Lightning Login if I use browser password manager and SF MFA?

Tags: mfa

I have the browser (Chrome) remember and auto-fill my passwords.
We are also using MFA for Salesforce (SF Authenticator).

With this scenario, is there any purpose or benefit from using Lightning Login?

--

About to roll out MFA for a large group of users, and contemplating disabling Lightning Login as unnecessary and having potential to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Your question presumes that everyone will be using a password manager. This is likely untrue. For better or worse, lots of people don't use a password manager for a variety of reasons. Maybe they can't because of policies, they don't want to log in to their password manager account just to save and load their Salesforce password, don't want to use a specific password manager account on a given computer, etc. By taking away Lightning Login, you're making more difficult for some subclass of your users that can't, or won't, use a password manager. Unless you have compelling evidence that Lightning Login is actually confusing your users, I would advise against disabling it.